# Не могу понять как импортировать библиотеки в vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, library

```
import numpy as np
```

Ошибка:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, суть в том что все нужные научные библиотеки уже установлены вместе с анакондой, но не могу никак импортировать библиотеки в фай. Неужели нужно каждый раз при создании проекта создавать отдельную папку с библиотеками? Есть какая-нибудь возможность указывать путь к библиотеке в самом .py файле? Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111592/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, попробуйте установить само расширение python в VS CODE. Перезапустите приложение и создайте новый файл.py

После этого опробуйте его с помощью простой команды. Если все будет работать, то впишите , к примеру, `import requests`.

Если пойдет загрузка, попробуйте `import numpy`

Дальше попробуйте `import numpy as np`

на крайняк, попробуйте в powershell, в самой программе, вписать `pip3 install numpy`